# Can not retrieve data from completely Loaded static variable AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, asynchronous

Basically I was trying to read an image in binary with help of URLLoader() and convert it to a image again in flash.

I wrote 2 static methods that one of them read image and set data properties to binary and other one is the COMPLETE handler. 
In COMPLETE handler I convert the binary data to **ByteArray** and assign it to a **static variable**. then tried to access to it from Main Timeline but it won't work.

The problem is my temporary variable not fully loading the **static variable** and when I'm checking **BytesAvailable** it's something like only 2.
What I'm doing wrong?

The COMPLETE handler:

```
public static function compHand(e:Event):void
    {
        var myByteArray:ByteArray = URLLoader(e.target).data as ByteArray;
        LoaderToObject.ImageBytes = myByteArray;

        trace(myByteArray.bytesAvailable);
        if (LoaderToObject.ImageBytes.length != myByteArray.length)
        {
            trace(myByteArray.length);
            trace(LoaderToObject.ImageBytes.length);
        }
        else
        {
            trace("successFully loaded!");
        }

    }

public static function loadBin(FileUrl:String)
    {
        var imageBytes:ByteArray=new ByteArray();
        var binUrl:URLRequest = new URLRequest(FileUrl);
        var binLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(binUrl);
        binLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
        binLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,compHand);
        //trace(LoaderToObject.ImageBytes);
        trace(FileUrl);
    }
```

The function I used in main timeLine:

```
function loadfile(e:MouseEvent):void
  {
     LoaderToObject.loadBin("chick.bmp");//send file to URLLoader
     imageBytes= LoaderToObject.ImageBytes;
     MakeImage2(imageBytes);

  }
```

Please help me

Comment: can you show how the handler is added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because URLLoader is asynchronous, so When you try to access imageBytes, the imageBytes hasn't been load complete yet.

Your need to pass callback function to loadBin for been called when load complete

Here is an example

The load class

```
Class MyLoader  {

     private var callback:function;

     private var binLoader:URLLoader;

     public function load(FileUrl:String, $callback:Function):void
     {
         callback = $callback;

         //your code
         var imageBytes:ByteArray=new ByteArray();
         var binUrl:URLRequest = new URLRequest(FileUrl);
         binLoader = new URLLoader(binUrl);
         binLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
         binLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,compHand);
         //trace(LoaderToObject.ImageBytes);
         trace(FileUrl);
     }

     private function compHand(e:Event):void
     {
         var myByteArray:ByteArray = URLLoader(e.target).data as ByteArray;

         if (callback != null)
         {
              callback(myByteArray, this);
         }

      }
}
```

LoaderToObject's load function

```
//make MyLoader class live, it's important
private var loadValidDic:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

public static function loadBin(FileUrl:String, callback:Function)
{
     var loader:MyLoader = new MyLoader();

     loadValidDic[loader] = callback;

     loader.load(FileUrl, internalComplete);
}

private static function internalComplete(ba:ByteArray, loader:MyLoader):void
{
    var callback:function = loadValidDic[loader];

    if (callback)
    {
        callback(ba);

        loadValidDic[loader] = null;

        delete loadValidDic[loader];
    }
}
```

Used in timeline

```
function loadfile(e:MouseEvent):void
{
     LoaderToObject.loadBin("chick.bmp", onComplete);//send file to URLLoader
}

private function onComplete(imageBytes:ByteArray):void
{
    MakeImage2(imageBytes);
}
```

Comment: how and where should I do it?

Comment: I think you answer need some cleanup, but it's ok! I'll do it later. thank you :)